# TypeScript - Use a generic type for a function

Tags: typescript

If I have a function:

```js
const flip = (A, B) => [B, A]
```

Add types to it:

```
const flip: <T1, T2>(A: T1, B: T2) => [T2, T1]
  = <T1, T2>(A: T1, B: T2) => [B, A];
```

Then extract the type:

```
type FlipFunction<T1, T2> = (A: T1, B: T2) => [T2, T1];
```

How can I use this type for an arrow function (function expression)?

Unfortunately this errors:

```
export const flip: FlipFunction<T1, T2>
  = <T1, T2>(A: T1, B: T2) => [B, A];
```

> Cannot find name 'T1'.

As does this:

```
export const flip: <T1, T2>FlipFunction<T1, T2>
  = <T1, T2>(A: T1, B: T2) => [B, A];
```

> (' expected.

[playground for the above](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgNgSzDArgOwMbAQezQHgBUBGAGikICYA+KAXigAoBBALgrKgCF2qBKerQDaVciQC6AbgBQEAB5gcAJ2BQMeAM6qAZojDF2RTlWotenHhUoC6w0R3H0oRsTTMdyl-oKhCu5ZilZBWVVdTQtKF0kSnZ4JFRMbDwXK1oGVJN3Ek9eax8-AKD5RRU1TR09AGZDHLT45HQsXAI6kydMtzYPbjybYX8oQMkgA)

Using a function declaration unfortunately doesn't seem to be an option:

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22063

*edit:* for the problem I'm trying to solve, the type `FlipFunction` above is already defined, but as an interface, that I can't change

e.g.

```
interface Component<C,T> extends ComponentBase<ComponentProps<C,T>>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the `flip` to be a generic function, do this instead-

```
type FlipFunction = <T1, T2>(A: T1, B: T2) => [T2, T1];
export const flip2: FlipFunction = <T1, T2>(A: T1, B: T2) => [B, A];
```

[[Playground]](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgNgSzDArgOwMbAQezVAXigB4AVARgBopSAmAPgAoBBALhqqgCF26BKQvSgBtOtQoBdANwAoCAA8wOAE7AoGPAGc1AM0Rha7eElSZseQiQriGLXpx41aAgkOFdqzaUA)

### Explanation

When you are declaring `FlipFunction` as `type FlipFunction<T1, T2> = (A: T1, B: T2) => [T2, T1];`, it means you need to provide the concrete types for `T1` and `T2` while declaring the variable of type `FlipFunction`.

Taking a simpler example-

```
type MyType<T> = T

const myVar: MyType<string> = "lorem";
```

Here the type of `myVar` is `string` which we provided as concrete type in place of the generic `T`.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense and may help (still thinking it through), but unfortunately for the problem I'm trying to solve, I can't edit the type as it's already defined externally. I've added a clarification to the question.


If I've understood your answer correctly, this wouldn't be possible by design, as my type for FlipFunction requires the types to be known at the point of definition, not at the point of being called.

Comment: What is your exact use case? Could you please write the type of imported declaration and also minimal use case for it.

Comment: The exact use case is fairly complex, and I was trying a few different routes to type it, one of the routes I got stuck with this and tried to distill it down to this issue, but I'll try describe the full issue here:


I want a React component that looks like this:


```
const StyledHeading: styled('h1')<{size: number}>();
const Heading = ({ level, ...props }) => {
  return <StyledHeading size={LEVEL_SIZE[level]} {...props} />;
};
```

Comment: StyledHeading's type is defined by StyledComponent and StyledComponentBase here https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/72b06d532e6b0f44c092a9348e53484a84af0be4/types/styled-components/index.d.ts#L153-L189


StyledComponentBase has a call signature to provide a polymorphic `as` prop. I want to inherit this call signature in my type for Heading as that I get the polymorphic `as` prop, which when used would allow additional props.

Comment: Your answer has already helped me get a much better understanding of what is happening though, so I'll try typing it again with this in mind.